# How to put the menu on bottom of slider

Tags: html, css

How to put the menu on bottom slider like the rectangle on this screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0155gr5z23

This is the current site http://162.213.158.24/~pizzakin/

I'm already try to fix it but the layout is changed when I try to open it on larger screen.

Thank you,

Adi

Comment: I think the site has a couple of problems in terms of responsiveness. For me the menu disappears in a viewport less than 1000px wide.

Comment: yes, I'm also need to fix it, but I should focus on this issue first

Comment: Give the parent `div` of `layersli` and `home-menu` an ID or class, make that `{ display: block: position: relative }` and make its children `position: absolute`. That way you can position them erverywhere you want. Give `home-menu { z-index: 'a number above-slider' }`, so you can put it on top of the slider. And...happy debugging

Comment: Thank you @RenevanderLende. It's already fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all
It's fixed after I use this css

```
z-index: 10; 
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px; 
top: auto; 
opacity: 1;
```